# Understanding how indirection works Python

Tags: python, arrays, output

I'm new to python. I had a difficult time understanding why the output would be 2 for the problem below. Can someone explain it to be in very basic terms.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
b = [3, 0, 2, 4, 1]
c = [3, 2, 4, 1, 5]

print c[a[a[4]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it helps understanding splitting it in 3 rows ?

```
inner_one = a[4] # a[4] = 0
inner_two = a[inner_one] # a[0] = 1
result = c[inner_two] # c[1] = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Python lists are 0-indexed.  So your first call, `a[4]`, returns `0`, then `a[0]` returns `1`, and finally `c[1]` returns `2`.